# what is meaning of 'end +' in ruby's function?

Tags: ruby

This is ruby function :

```
def long_reference_name
  if suite?
    "#{recursive_access} #{recursive_view} "
  else
    ""
  end + reference_name
end
```

I don't understand what's the meaning of:

`end + reference_name`

Comment: Akash, you should mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It’s not `end + reference_name`, it’s `<previous expression> + reference_name`, where `<previous_expression>` is:

```
if suite?
 "#{recursive_access} #{recursive_view} "
else
""
end
```

Because blocks are expressions with values in Ruby.

In other words, you have either `"#{recursive_access} #{recursive_view} " + reference_name` or `"" + reference_name`, depending on the value of `suite?`.

Answer (score 4):

This is method `+` called on result of `if-else-end` statement.

As an example see below :

```
m = if true  
  "abc"
else
  "xyz"
end + "mm" 
# => "abcmm"
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers explain how to read it. They don't examine that it's not a good thing to imitate.

Adding something to the result of the conditional test could have been done cleanly using:

```
def foo(s)
  ret = if (s == "something")
    'some text'
  else
    ''
  end
  ret + reference_name
end
```

It's one line extra, just as fast, but more understandable.

Technically and syntactically the other way works but it's not as idiomatic and that affects maintenance.

Comment: +1, but I must admit, I personally do like Perley hacks like this in Ruby.

Comment: The problem with "perly hacks" is  that they invite many other Perl practices, which collectively result in what has been called line-noise. I've written a lot of Perl code and could get down and dirty with it, but always preferred readability over obscurity. If I have to reread something to figure out what it's doing, it's wasting my time.